# From where to download phonegap/cordova folder

Tags: cordova

Currently am using phonegap 2.3.0.A few days ago Phonegap site link phonegap.com/install/   shown the all folders of phonegap . But now there is no any phonegap version folder.They change their sites layout. Am not using CLI.I just copy the phonegap js and jar files into my project folder. Now,I want to download the phonegap new version folder.So please suggest me the link from where i can download the phonegap/cordova folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my suggestion is u must create cordova project in CLI which is useful to add the custom plugins.

[Cordova CLI guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/)

Comment: If I create project with CLI then, then it give error.[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22". I don't want to download that.

Comment: Yes if u already update cordova version for android it must need android-22 sdk version,my personal advice u hv to use cordova project which is created through CLI,Because i facing lots for problem with phonegap project (js,jar files) in my earlier days.

Comment: you need to download android sdk 22 if you want to create android apps